# What is the use of returning [...list] in Dart?

Tags: list, dart, return-value

In Dart programming language, sometimes I see functions returning a list in pair of brackets with triple dots `[...list]`. For example:

```
class IntList {
    List<int> _integerList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    List<int> get integerList {
        return [..._integerList];
    }
}
```

So what is the difference between `return integerList;` and the above return statement?

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case there is no difference. `...` is the spread operator. This allows you to insert multiple elements into a collection.

For example:

```dart
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var list2 = [0, ...list];
print(list2)

Output:
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

So doing `return [..._integerList];` is the exact same as return `integerList;`, other than that it creates a new list.

---

```dart
var list = [1, 2, 3];
print(list.hashCode);
print([...list].hashCode);
```

This code shows that they are *different* `List` objects when the spread operator is used because of the output of different hash codes.

Comment: Can you explain more about the creation of a new list?

Comment: @CodeNewbie It's creating a new `List` object instead of reusing the existing one *I believe*. I not 100% sure on that however.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I believe I am correct. It creates a new `List` Object. I added a sample to my answer that shows this.

Comment: "For this particular case there is no difference... other than that it creates a new list"... Creating a copy is the entire reason for using the spread operator this way.  You don't want the caller the be able to mutate your object's internal list directly.

Comment: For that porpoise you can also use [UnmodifiableListView](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-collection/UnmodifiableListView-class.html) or [List.unmodifiable](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/List.unmodifiable.html) (I think the difference is that `UnmodifiableListView` creates a view of the Iterable while `List.unmodifiable` creates an entire new list).
If you try to mutate that list an error will be thrown

Comment: `List.from` would also create a new instance just like using spread would and it would allow the caller to still mutate the *new* `List` unlike `List.unmodifiable`.